# How can I set my Feed importer to unlimited?

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting

I'm trying to import a list from SharePoint 2010 to Drupal 7 but it only imports/creates 10 nodes, while there are more items in the list.

I've tried adding `$conf['feeds_process_limit'] = 0;`  in the **settings.php** and clearing the cache, but no luck.

Also tried to change `define('FEEDS_PROCESS_LIMIT', 50);` in the **FeedsProcessor.inc** file.

It doesn't matter where I change a number, it sticks to 10. And I can't find any setting that's 10.

Best regards,
Stefki

Comment: Some more Sherlock-styled-investigating (Heavy drinking and banging my head against the wall) led to the solution:

It wasn't the Feed importer itself, but the integrated SharePoint fetcher/parser.

In the SharePoint-module is a file called sharepoint.inc, open it, find $rowLimit = 10 (near line 60) and change it to the limit you want. NULL for unlimited.

That's it!